# awk code in file comparision

Tags: awk, nawk

two files which has component name and version number separated by a space:

```
cat file1
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.9
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65

cat file2 
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 95.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.0.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
com.acc.invm:distri_cob 110
```

desired output :

```
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 95.0.5
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
```

needed output is: All components from file1 with a higher version than in file2 in only in first decimal position.

in desired output "com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD" is coming because 96(in file1) > 95(in file2)

"com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment" is not coming because 94.1.6(in file1) 94.0.6 ( in file2), first decimal value is same (94=94).

tried awk code but no luck.

```
tst.awk
{ split($2,a,/\./); curr = a[1]*10000 + a[2]*100 + a[3] }
NR==FNR { prev[$1] = curr; next }
!($1 in prev) || (curr > prev[$1])
/usr/bin/nawk -f file2 file1 tst.awk
```

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your statement(*only in first decimal position*), you don't need the `curr = a[1]*10000 + a[2]*100 + a[3]`. Just use `curr = a[1]` would be fine.

As your desired output only contain the line both in file1 and file2, so `($1 in prev) && (curr > prev[$1])` is needed.

```
{split($2,a,/\./); curr = a[1];}
NR==FNR {prev[$1] = curr; next }
($1 in prev) && (curr > prev[$1])
```

**DEMO**

```
lo@ubuntu:~$ cat f1
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 94.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.1.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.9
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.6.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 12.23.65

lo@ubuntu:~$ cat f2
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 95.0.5
com.acc.invm:FNS_TEST_DCCC_Mangment 94.0.6
com.acc.invm:FNS_APIPlat_BDMap 100.0.10
com.acc.invm:SendEmail 29.60.113
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65
com.acc.invm:distri_cob 110

lo@ubuntu:~$ awk -f t.awk f1 f2
com.acc.invm:FNS_PROD 95.0.5
com.acc.invm:SendSms 133.28.65

lo@ubuntu:~$ cat t.awk 
{split($2,a,/\./); curr = a[1];}
NR==FNR {prev[$1] = curr; next }
($1 in prev) && (curr > prev[$1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ Version = $2 
       sub( /[.].*/, "", Version)
       if ( FNR == NR ) Versionning[ $1] = Version
        else if( Versionning[ $1] < Version) print
     }' file1 file2
```

You can adapt the last *if* to discard non existing line/product in file 1 changing the condition with `Versionning [ $1] != "" && Versionning[ $1] < Version`